# React hook state updated in parent but child component does not receive new props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using a css grid layout with a differing amount of columns and rows based on screen size.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function Main() {

  const [numRows, setNumRows] = useState(10)
  const [numColumns, setNumColumns] = useState(10)

  const layoutList = [
      <Content {...props} />,
      <Content {...props2} />,
      <Profile {...props3} numColumns={numColumns} />,
    ]

  const [layout, setLayout] = useState(layoutList)

  let gridCount = () => {
    //code to count number of columns and rows
    //uses setNumRows and setNumColumns passed down as props
  }

}
```

After creating a layout of my components I define a function to count the num of rows and columns.

```
useEffect(() => {
  gridCount()
  window.addEventListener("resize", gridCount)
})
```

I add a resize eventlistener which works, I can see that state is being updated in the parent component Main. However when I check the state of the child component Profile I see that it was initialized with 10 but never gets accessed again, no new props are being sent to even though the Main state is being updated correctly.  I'm trying to get a rerender in the child but I'm unsure why the parent is not sending updated props, any state change in the parent should cause a rerender correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly from the code available, but I suspect the children do not receive the new props because those children are stored in state and never updated.

To fix this you should update the children whenever you update `numRows` or `numColumns`. Since there isn't usually a good reason to store children in a state variable (and it can lead to issues like this where you have to manually tell the children to update instead of letting React handle that), I would recommend removing the state storage for `layout` entirely and just rendering the children like usual. Just use `layoutList` directly in your returned element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I didn't know storing children in state could cause issues like that, the reason I did so was I wanted to change the layout dynamically based on other factors.  I'll see if I can find a workaround but for my reference is there anyway to force the children to rerender if stored in state?

Comment: You can redefine `layoutList` and pass it to `setLayout`, but again, I would advise against this as React will handle updating children when relevant. Basically, it's enough to just pass props to the children and they will update accordingly.